# How can I enable client certificate ios 12 so that chrome uses it

Tags: google-chrome, security, ios12, mobile-chrome

On iOS 12, safari presents the client certificate and I am able to choose it and proceed to website because the client certificate was authenticated successfully.

Chrome doesn’t ask and therefore fails to authenticate with the server.

In earlier versions of iOS, there was setting to allow app like chrome to trust an installed client certificate in the Profiles.

Where is the setting located now to allow chrome to use the profile/client cert that is installed on iOS?  I’m up to date with iOS 12.3.1

Comment: In my device, I do not have toggle to enable trust as shown in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477 for the self signed cert that I created and installed on the iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Apps can only access keychain items in their own keychain access groups. This means that items in the Apple access group are only available to Apple-provided apps such as Safari or Mail. according to [QA1745](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html)

That means that the Client Certificate validation function cannot be provided in Chrome unless the Chrome browser itself handles the installation and provision of Client Certificates. Based on my research in the last few days, there doesn't seem to be a clear method to directly install client certificates in Chrome. This is also a problem that is causing me trouble.